# Can't align unordered lists with 'flex-column'

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am creating a vertical nav - top ul list will align to top and the other one to the bottom. Right now my nav looks like two columns instead of one long list of items: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3pmwuih7xij51fj/Screen%20Shot%202019-12-28%20at%2010.41.34%20PM.png?dl=0

Here is a quick photoshop work to show what I am expecting (all menu items in one column):
[image]

I tried adding w-100 but I can't get them to align to one col. How do I create a break between the two?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1" style="background-color: aliceblue; height: 600px;">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md flex-column p-0"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">logo</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
          <ul class="navbar-nav flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a> </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="navbar-nav flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show an image of what is being expected?

Comment: Here you go-- image at the top

Comment: figured it out, you can check the added answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add ***flex-column*** to the div ***#navbarsExampleDefault*** and between the 2 ***ul*** you can add ***hr*** to seperate them out and later style it.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-1" style="background-color: aliceblue; height: 600px;">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md flex-column p-0"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">logo</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-column" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex-column">
                    <li class="nav-item active"> 
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                            Help <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                        </a> 
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a> </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a> </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a> </li>
                </ul>
                <hr>
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex-column">
                    <li class="nav-item active"> 
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                            Help <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                        </a> 
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a> </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a> </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. Feels a bit hacky having to insert a <hr> just to break things!

Comment: or you can use additional margin for the first unordered list, even that would work